# assigning odds to an array of size 50

Tags: c

Here is a simple c code in code blocks. In this code i want to assign odd numbers from 1 to 100 into an array of size 50 and then print them all going fine but the last element i.e, odd[49] instead of assigning 99 it gives 49 anyone to go through my code and find the error.Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i, k;
    int odd[49];

    for(i=1; i<100; i++)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
            continue;
        else
            odd[(i-1)/2]=i;
    }

    for(k=0; k<50; k++)
        printf("(%d)%d\n", k, odd[k]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The array isn't big enough. Make it `int odd[50]`

Comment: The memory of `odd[49]` might be the same as for `k`.

Comment: You are confusing declaring an array with accessing an array. When declaring an array, type 50 if you want 50 elements. When accessing an array, type [49] if you wish to access the 50th element, since array indexing starts at zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already pointed out you only reserve room for 49 integers in the array.

Besides fixing that bug you should simplify your code by using `2*i + 1` for calculating odd numbers. All you need is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int odd[50];         // 50 instead of 49

    for(i=0;i<50;i++)    // Start from 0
        odd[i]=2*i+1;    // then 2*i+1 will give you 1 3 5 7 ...

    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
        printf("(%d)%d\n",i,odd[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: quite usefull acually i thought that but as i  am a maths student i used 2i+1 instead of 2*i+1 as we use in maths but the compiler gave some error so i figured out this way

Answer (score 0):

```
int odd[49];
```

Is supposed to hold only `49` elements and you need `50`.
Accessing `50`th element of an array that is supposed to hold `49` elements is `UB`. You could have got anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your array holds only 49 values. Convert it to

> int odd[50]

to store 50 values.